# How Can I Search This in the Web Page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-re

Hello I am coding stock monitor bot with python for hype shoes. Other web site I using request and re modules. I send the request and search in the web site "sold out" text with `re`.

I hope you understand me. But this time. This website little bit hard. https://www.nike.com/tr/launch/t/air-jordan-1-white-royal I want to track this website but it has very hard and complex code.

How can I track:

```
if re.search('(?i)Sepete Ekle', req1.text):
    print('White Royal Checked STOCKED!!!')
else:
    print('White Royal Checked NOSTOCK')
```